# iOS GPS Altitude measurement

Tags: ios, iphone, gps

I have a simple question. Does anybody know (and have a link to a doku) if the iPhones that include a barometer is using it automatically to improve altitude readings in CLLocation?

Comment: I don't believe that it does. The barometer is not calibrated for sea-level, it is merely used to calculate relative altitude changes, such as climb flights of stairs

Comment: Yep, but would be nice to know if iOS uses the relative change information to verify it's readings?!? Do you know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So with some really really bad GPS-Tracks lately I know that iPhone is not using the build in barometer (horrible ups and downs in altitude). I manually have to correct the altitude reading using air-pressure after calibrating to altitude-readings I consider to be accurate.